fetchCookie Is Not A Function
Maybe I becoming blind, but I don't see where I am wrong.
I would use commonjs interface of fetch-cookie.
According to the documentation, this is possible, indeed.
https://github.com/valeriangalliat/fetch-cookie?tab=readme-ov-file#development
So, I tried:
const fetchCookie = require('fetch-cookie')
const tough = require('tough-cookie');
const username = 'x';
const password = 'x';
 
// Create a cookie jar
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();

// Wrap fetch with fetch-cookie and the created cookie jar
const fetchWithCookies = fetchCookie(fetch, cookieJar);

but:
❯ node testfetch.js 
const fetchWithCookies = fetchCookie(fetch, cookieJar);
                         ^


TypeError: fetchCookie is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/testfetch.js:15:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)


Are you using v1 or v2?

maybe a stupid question, but if its not a function what is it then? it might be set up as a ESM module and so be using require() you might get an object holding all the content including the function you're looking for.

The function you're looking for is exported as default. It's a bit awkward in CommonJS, but you can reference it explicitly:
const fetchCookie = require('fetch-cookie').default;
// Here -----------------------------------^

